# How to group by two dependent columns and generate new unique key using python pandas or networkx lib?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-science, networkx

We are trying to create new identification number (unique key) for finding unique customer using python pandas or python network graph(networkx lib):

Two columns depending on each other(vice-versa), need to group by both the columns and generate a new unique key.

Below is a list of the sample data in python pandas dataframe.

Input data set:

```
    r_vid   d_ph_nm    d_flg
    DQLA853 6123340277  N
    DQLA851 6999045706  N
    DQLA851 6999340277  Y
    DQLCT41 6999045706  N
    DQLCT41 7123104672  N
    DQLCT41 9123010121  N
    DQLA852 6999290277  N
    DQLA962 6999290277  Y
    DQLC181 6222232026  N
    DQLT381 6222232026  N
    DQLC860 9912332326  N
    DQLC860 9912336579  N
```

Output data set:

```
    r_vid_group        d_ph_nm_group                              new_unique_id
    DQLA851,DQLCT41   6999045706,6999340277,7123104672,9123010121     123
    DQLA852,DQLA962   6999290277                                      124
    DQLA853           6123340277                                      125
    DQLC181,DQLT381   6222232026                                      126
    DQLC860           9912332326,9912336579                           127
```

Could you please suggest in python pandas or python pandas network graph(networkx lib).

Comment: what is the logic to get from input to output? group by colors?

Comment: @luigigi the logic is [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) in a graph network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pretty wide workaround using individual items as unique identifiers:

```
new_ids_simple = {}
new_ids_map = {}
i=0
for d_ph_nm, r_vid in df[['d_ph_nm','r_vid']].values:

    if all([x not in new_ids_map.keys() for x in [d_ph_nm, r_vid]]):
        new_ids_map[d_ph_nm] = i
        new_ids_map[r_vid] = i
        new_ids_simple[i] = {'d_ph_nm':[d_ph_nm],'r_vid':[r_vid]}
        i+=1
    else:
        # retrieving unique value:
        None
        for x in [d_ph_nm, r_vid]:
            if x in new_ids_map.keys():
                new_val = new_ids_map.get(x)
            else:
                new_key = x
        # setting unique value
        new_ids_map[new_key] = new_val
        new_ids_simple[new_val]['d_ph_nm'].append(d_ph_nm)
        new_ids_simple[new_val]['r_vid'].append(r_vid)


map_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_ids_simple,orient='index')
map_df.index.names = ['ID']
map_df['d_ph_nm'] = map_df['d_ph_nm'].apply(pd.unique)
map_df['r_vid'] = map_df['r_vid'].apply(pd.unique)

# To convert from an array to a string (inside the df)
map_df['r_vid'] = map_df['r_vid'].apply(', '.join)

                                           d_ph_nm             r_vid
ID                                                                  
0                                       6123340277           DQLA853
1   6999045706, 6999340277, 7123104672, 9123010121  DQLA851, DQLCT41
2                                       6999290277  DQLA852, DQLA962
3                                       6222232026  DQLC181, DQLT381
4                           9912332326, 9912336579           DQLC860
```

Comment: Thank you!  @Yaakov Bressler
Its working fine!! 
I want to remove array braces ([]) from result and need to store final result into csv file with pipe delimiter.

Comment: You can join each array to a comma separated string with an apply function.

Comment: could you please give more details for convert Array to String values including single quote '' comma separated values.

Comment: Thank you @Yaakov Bressler it's working fine. i have converted float data type for d_ph_nm column.  
float type array list converted into string array list:
`map_df['d_ph_nm'] = [','.join(map(str, l)) for l in map_df['d_ph_nm']]`

Comment: Great to hear! @SrinivasK -- if you think my answer is useful, consider giving it an upvote? :)

Answer (score 2):

You might try this:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'r_vid', 'd_ph_nm', create_using=nx.Graph())

# If you want to picture the graph
#fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10))
#nx.draw_networkx(G, ax=ax)

dfgroup = pd.DataFrame()
for n, i in enumerate(nx.connected_components(G)):
    arr = np.array(list(i))
    s = [node in df['r_vid'].tolist() for node in i]
    node_r = arr[s]
    t = [node in df['d_ph_nm'].tolist() for node in i]
    node_d = arr[t]
    df_r = pd.DataFrame({'r_vid_group':[node_r], 
                         'd_ph_num_group':[node_d]},
                        index=[n]) 
    dfgroup = pd.concat([dfgroup,df_r])

dfgroup = dfgroup.rename_axis('new_unique_id').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   new_unique_id         r_vid_group                                     d_ph_nm_group
0              0           [DQLA853]                                      [6123340277]
1              1  [DQLA851, DQLCT41]  [7123104672, 9123010121, 6999045706, 6999340277]
2              2  [DQLA852, DQLA962]                                      [6999290277]
3              3  [DQLC181, DQLT381]                                      [6222232026]
4              4           [DQLC860]                          [9912336579, 9912332326]
```

Comment: What does `from_pandas_edgelist` do?

Comment: It take columns from a pandas dataframe and creates edges with a source and target node.

Comment: Thank you -- @Scott Boston


I'm facing below issue: 
may be my server having different networkx api

Error: AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'from_pandas_edgelist'

Comment: @SrinivasK I am using Networkx 2.... in networkx 1 the function name was [`from_panda_dataframe`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_dataframe.html)

Comment: @SrinivasK [Here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/release/release_2.0.html) is the documentation of change in the API.